# Can concept checking be delayed till class instantiation in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

A common practice to speed up compilation is to only declare classes instead of giving their full definitions, e.g.

```
struct A;
template<typename T> struct B;
using C = B<A>;
```

By if one likes to use C++20 concepts in template classes then the code as follows

```
#include <concepts>
struct A;
template<std::destructible T> struct B;
using C = B<A>;
```

will result in error:

```
error: template constraint failure for 'template<class T>  requires  destructible<T> struct B'
     | using C = B<A>;
```

Is it possible to somehow delay the moment of concept checking till `B<A>` is really used/instantiated? If not, then it seems that concepts will significantly slow down compilation of some programs by forcing to include class definitions which were previously hidden.

Comment: What would be fine would be to forward declare with information (as concept, inheritance, ...).

Comment: `static_assert` in `B` instead of concept it :/

Comment: It would basically defeat the purpose of concepts that is to report errors early.

Comment: If it was possible, I can see it leading to some pathological situations. You can do things with incomplete types (`C*`, `C&` and even `C foo( C );` are valid). If the compiler didn't check it on the spot, you could end up with lots of code referring to a type that doesn't really exist. Seems wrong.

Comment: the concept decides whether the specialization exists not whether it can be made complete. There are many situations where one is using incomplete types and then its a problem when the concept does not kick in yet

Comment: Side question: do you have to use header files? If you are using C++20 then use of  modules will make this problem not existent.

Comment: Yes, for now I am stuck to header files. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you forward declare.

```
struct A;
template<class T> struct B;
using C = B<A>;
```

keep this.  In `B.h`:

```
#include <concepts>
template<class T> struct B;
// or
template<class T> struct B
{
  static_assert( std::destructible<T> );
};

template<std::destructible T>
struct B<T> {
};
```

specialize.  Leave the base `B<T>` undefined.

Now, the errors you get aren't going to be checked "early", but rather occur at a later spot.  So passing `T` to `B<>` won't check in a SFINAE-friendly way.

But that basically is what you asked not to happen in your question.

Note that the `static_assert` may, under certain readings of the standard, make your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required.  Basically all specializations (including the base one) must have a valid instantiation, and pattern matching of the other specialization makes this impossible.

But in practice I think you just get an error message.

Comment: Thanks, it work! The only nuisance is that instead of concept violation, the error will be about `incomplete type B`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/naWe6cbxf

Comment: @Fedor Yes.  Add `{ static_assert( std::destructible<T> ); };` as the implementation of the base specialization for a bit of a hint to the end user.