# C++20 concepts and incomplete types

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, incomplete-type

I'm forward declaring a type and providing its definition later down the line. Once it has been fully defined it is expected to meet some requirements, and to be a suitable template argument. However, when pairing incomplete types with C++20 concepts I run into problems.

The following compiles without a hitch using GCC 13.2.0:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
class class_without_constrained_template {};

struct A;
struct B;

struct B { class_without_constrained_template<A> var; };
struct A {};

int main() {
  return 0;
};
```

If I try to formalize the requirements using C++20 concepts compilation fails, and the compiler complains that `A` is not `std::destructible`:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <std::destructible T>
class class_with_constrained_template {};

struct A;
struct B;

struct B { class_with_constrained_template<A> var; };
struct A {};

int main() {
  return 0;
};
```

I realize that at the time of defining `B`, `A` is an incomplete type that does not fulfill the requirements. However, it would fulfill them by the time you were instantiating it. I have found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68556093/can-concept-checking-be-delayed-till-class-instantiation-in-c), but the proposed solution does not seem to work when `class_with_constrained_template` is used as a member variable. The following fails to compile.

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
class class_with_constrained_template {
  static_assert( std::destructible<T> );
};

template <std::destructible T>
class class_with_constrained_template<T> {};

struct A;
struct B;

struct B { class_with_constrained_template<A> _; };
struct A {};

int main() {
  return 0;
};
```

In the above snippet, when is `static_assert` evaluated, and why does it evaluate to `false`? Is it possible to use C++20 concepts in this scenario? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, it would fulfill them by the time you were instantiating it

No. Thats not right. `B` is a class. It is not a template. It is nothing that gets instantiation later. You define it and thats it. In the Q&A you link the `B` is a template that is instantiated later only when the needed type is complete.

If you make `B` a template, the answer from the other question applies:

```
#include <concepts>

template <class T>
class class_with_constrained_template {
  static_assert( std::destructible<T> );
};

template <std::destructible T>
class class_with_constrained_template<T> {};

struct A;

template <typename T = A>
struct B { class_with_constrained_template<T> _; };
struct A {};


int main() {
    B<> a;
};
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7c9z6qdK8)